# Restore Time Machine onto smaller SSD drive

Tags: time-machine, ssd, restore

I have a 2012(?) macmini at home and last night I backed up my HDD to Time Machine then moved the 1TB HDD to the 2nd bay and installed a new 250GB SSD into the 1st bay.
I formatted the new drive to Mac OS Journaled and rebooted.
Now I have tried to restore from Time Machine, but my backup (after excluded folders) is about 375GB.
I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to alter the time machine backup and delete folders I know I have backups elsewhere to get this under 250GB and then restore from that?
2. If 1 is not possible, how do I reboot to use the original HDD again and redo my Time Machine backup for essential files only?

I've read other questions which say try a clean install, but it would take me days to re-configure my system the way I need it, so that is not an option.

I have a full backup on external HD as well as full cloud backup.

Comment: Although you can delete files/links out of the `latest` backup folder, it is not recommended. You can choose boot devices on startup by pressing and holding the Option (Alt) key. But isn't the system you booted still the old one, seeing that you just formatted the new drive?

Comment: It booted to the old system on first start-up after disk swap, but once I formatted the new disk, I think it only then mounted it as the system disk so on restart it used that and not the old.

Comment: Which means you didn't just format it, but actually installed an operating system onto it, right? But still, simply hold Option during boot (or alternatively choose a startup disk from the Settings app).

Comment: No as on startup it asked me to install or restore from Time Machine which was what I wanted to do. I could install the OS but thinking that is unnecessary if I'm going to restore over it later. You have partly answered my question with point 2 anyway. I'll try and go back to original HDD at home tonight and see if I can do it that way. Thanks

Comment: Cool. Actually, restoring from time machine implies an OS installation, as the backup only contains non-system files and folders. Your Mac has a recovery partition and even pulls the OS installer from the App Store on demand.

Comment: Yeah - I've done that before on my MBP. If I could just delete my itunes and iphoto libraries from the Time Machine backup, I'm sure it would fit on the new SSD and then restore the libraries later on to the old HDD from somewhere else which would be ideal. Slightly annoying that I'll have to do another ~250GB backup tonight after last night. 
Any reason why you say it's not recommended to delete files?

Comment: @sekdiy, If you're making this statement, "_as the backup only contains non-system files and folders._" in reference to Time Machine, then you are absolutely wrong. Sans exclusions Time Machine backups up the entire Macintosh HD.

Comment: @user3439894 I still use 'System' in the original Mac OS system (folder) sense, i.e. a TM backup isn't bootable on its own. ;)

Comment: @TomC Deleting files isn't officially recommended (as far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong), which doesn't mean it wouldn't work. I've done it and so could you as long as you know what you're doing. But since it's hardly reversible and you're having other options, it wouldn't be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: @sekdiy, Your statement, _only contains non-system files_ in ref to Time Machine is still factually wrong since a Time Machine backup can be restored to an empty disk and then the disk to with it was restored if a functioning OS and can be booted! (This assumes one hasn't deleted required system files from the backup.)  As to your comment "_Deleting files isn't officially recommended_" please stop making statements you can't backup with official documentation!  If it wasn't officially supported then Apple wouldn't have designed in a way to delete files/folders from the Time Machine interface!

Comment: It's the `can be restored` part for which you need a bootable machine or restore media. And although that may come pre-installed on most Macs, it can't be assumed after a new SSD had been built in. As for the support to fiddle with a TM backup for purposes of a system restore (as opposed to simply finding a couple of files), show me the Apple support document where they explain it. Until then I simply refuse to be the guy who recommends it as long as there are other options left.

Comment: Ok - I have now made a backup that is less than 200GB and it still says there's not enough space on the 250GB drive. Any ideas?

Comment: And if I try to delete from the TM backup, I get the following error: `The operation can't be completed because backup items can't be modified`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up answering my own question as follows:

1. I wasn't able to delete files from the Time Machine backup and got the following message: `The operation can't be completed because backup items can't be modified`
2. I rebooted using Command+R and then tried to restore from Time Machine. I kept getting errors saying the new drive was too small. I then installed OSX onto the new drive and then did the restore which worked ok.

Answer (score -1):

Create a fusion drive using SSD and hardrive.
It will work

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review